# React Native: I removed rn-fetch-blob, and now another package throws an error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, package.json, redux-persist, rn-fetch-blob

I was using `rn-fetch-blob` in my React Native app. I replaced it with `react-native-blob-util`. I'm also using `redux-persist-filesystem-storage`, which uses `rn-fetch-blob`. `redux-persist-filesystem-storage` started throwing an error (`null is not an object (evaluating 'RNFetchBlob.DocumentDir')`) once I uninstalled `rn-fetch-blob`. I assumed that removing `node_modules/rn-fetch-blob` would have no effect on `redux-persist-filesystem-storage` since `redux-persist-filesystem-storage` uses `node_modules/redux-persist-filesystem-storage/node_modules/rn-fetch-blob`.

Is my reasoning correct here? What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this happens, because sometimes your package is not perfectly installed. So you can try installing rn-fetch-blob or again do a proper installation of redux-persist-filesystem-storage, because in the new version they already replaced rn-fetch-blob with react-native-blob-util.